# She’s very tall, as is her mother. Why "is" and "her mother" inversed of their position?

Tags: grammar

> She’s very tall, as is her mother.

Can I rephrease as below?

1. She's very tall, as her mother is tall.
2. She's very tall, as her mother is.
3. She's very tall as much as her mother.

3.2 She's very tall as much as her mother is tall.

3.3 She's very tall as much as her mother is.

4. She's very tall as her mother is tall.
5. She;s very tall as her mother is.
6. She's very tall as her mother.
7. She's very tall, as tall as her mother is tall.
8. She's very tall, as tall as her mother is.
9. She's very tall, as tall as her mother.

Main question was: She's very tall, as her mother is. (possible?)

Comment: *She takes after her mother in height.* is an option

Comment: Most of these are grammatically incorrect.  Several change the meaning (the original sentence says only that they're both tall; they may be different heights).

Comment: (2) is not only possible, but the _only_ one of your alternatives that is acceptable. ('As is her mother' is rather formal and old-fashioned.)

Comment: 8, and 9 are OK in informal speech, to this US English speaker.

Comment: as is her mother and as her mother is. any difference could be?

Comment: I have just told you what the difference is! (that _as is her mother_ is more formal). I agree with @stangdon that (8) and (9) are acceptable, but, as Ryan says, mean something slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

I think 2 is OK. 1 might be, but the original sentence is the idiomatic way to say it.

The other alternatives say that she and her mother are equally tall. You don't know that. All you know is that both are above average, with the inference that she inherited tallness.